# In Visual Studio 2012 c++ project where can I put my non-build related files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

So in MSVS c# projects, IIRC, you could make a project that is non-buildable (or something - been a while since I did c#). I used these kinds of projects to put a few files that where related to my project, but not really source code. For examples:

- Script (not build scripts) for running tests / other utils
- Notes (files that I want to look at in MSVS to read for ease of access - i.e. not via windows explorer)
- plantuml files (generates UML pictures from plantuml text files) - so .uml (text files) and .png (images).

So these files are not "Resource" files - when I add .bat files in there I get issues. They are not source of headers and I don't want them in there (although I can put them there).

I kind of want a general folder within a project to put stuff and/or a general project that does not attempt to do anything other then contain files (i.e. solution global).

so:

- Is there a way to create a category of file in a project?
- Is there a way to create a project in a solution that does not build / do anything?

Comment: If you make a cpp file in your VS solution and later you want to exclude it from build ( without physically deleting), you simply can remove the cpp file from the solution.

Comment: @seccpur thanks - I know that, what I am trying to get is to see the file in visual studio but not in the sources/headers category but in a category of my choice. E.g. I have a file call `abc.zxy`. Its not a source file, its not a build file. But I want to see it in my project somewhere so I can quickly look at it / edit it.

Comment: The removed cpp file still shows in the IDE for quick lookup, but won't affect in the compiling. It even gets save and will load the next time the solution opens.

Comment: @seccpur not as far as I can tell, if you remove it (but not delete it) it just disappears from the solution but you can still see it in windows explorer... but also this is not what I want - I want to categorise my non source files into a separate category or non-build-project.